# My VBA is not pulling the body of my saved email template

Tags: excel, vba

I am having some difficulty pulling the body of a saved email template into my VBA. I am using Office 2010. What I am doing is sending mass emails from Excel. Every time I send it I get a blank email with no body. I had this working with 2013. Is there something different between the years in coding?

```
Private Function GetRichTextTemplate() As String

Dim OLF As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olMailItem As Outlook.MailItem

Set OLF = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts)
Set oItems = OLF.Items

For Each Mailobject In oItems
    If Mailobject.subject = "2014 Year End Client Letter" Then
        GetRichTextTemplate = Mailobject.HTMLBody
        Exit Function
    End If
Next
```

End Function

Comment: I've been trying to work this out.  Have you stepped through the code to see that GetRichTextTemplate is being populated?  My guess is that GetRichTextTemplate isn't and that's why you're getting a blank email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert when it comes to Outlook/VBA but what I got to work to show that the Subject was being found and advancing to the next line `GetRichTextTemplate = Mailobject.HTMLBody` is this:

```
Private Function GetRichTextTemplate() As String

Dim OLF As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olMailItem As Outlook.MailItem

Set OLF = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set oItems = OLF.Items

For Each olMailItem In OLF.Items

    i = i + 1
    With OLF.Items(i)

    If .Subject = "2014 Year End Client Letter" Then
        GetRichTextTemplate = mailobject.HTMLBody
        Exit Function
    End If

    End With

Next

End Function
```